# Javascript Storing Information in URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, web-applications, store

I was wondering how (if it's possible) to store information in the URL of a webpage? I've noticed in websites like Youtube there is information stored in the URL (for example which video in a playlist) and I would like to know how to do this for a website I'm working on.

Comment: JavaScript is a client side language. You would need to use PHP $_GET

Comment: [What you're referring to is called a query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

Comment: What information do you want to store within URL?

Comment: You should read more about URL first to fully understand how it is structured and what parts it has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator You will find all your answers in the documentation.

Comment: This is a perfectly legitimate question... I have no idea why there are so many downvotes and close votes.

Comment: @Brad, Yes, I have the same question, that's why I ended up here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) of the URL is used for extra data and parameters.

```
http://example.com/some-page.html?a=something&b=something%20else
```

Everything after the question mark `?` is the query string.  This can be formatted however you want, but the most common way is the format of `key=value`, with ampersands `&` separating each variable.

Now, you might be wondering... what if you actually want an ampersand `&` or some other non-alpha-numeric character?  For that, you must use [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).

To access the query string in JavaScript, use `window.location.search`.  To actually parse the query string, see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/362536

You can set the query string in JavaScript if you want, by setting `window.location.search`... just know that you're reloading the page if you do.  Unless, you use [push/pop state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) which is a common way to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Myk If you found this answer useful, consider marking it as the accepted answer and/or up-voting.